# How to display a Checkbox with selected value and description

Tags: jquery

When the checkbox is selected its displaying selected value as  text 
How to make it display a Checkbox with text  and description appearing beside that .

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function (e) {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    var checkbox =  $("#sample").prepend('<div id="anotherdiv">' + $(this).attr('value') + '</div>');
                    $("#sample").prepend(checkbox); 
                }
                else {
                    $('#anotherdiv').remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="center" style= "margin-top: 150px;">
    <div id="sample"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/DtuA5/1/ ? Done only with css. check each checkbox to see its value next to checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand your question correctly but if you want the value of the value attribute appear before or after of checkboxes code will be:
html:

Before

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function (e) {   
        var id=$(this).attr('id')
        if($('#' + id).is(":checked")){
             $( '<span class="anotherdiv">' + $(this).attr('value') + '</span>').appendTo('body').insertBefore($(this)) 
            }else{
              $(this).prev().remove();  
            }
        })

    })
</script>
```

after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function (e) {
            var id=$(this).attr('id')
            if($('#' + id).is(":checked")){
                 $( '<span class="anotherdiv">' + $(this).attr('value') + '</span>').appendTo('body').insertAfter($(this)) 
                }else{
                  $(this).next().remove();  
                }
            })

        })
    </script>
```

html:

```
 <input id="a"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"><br>
 <input id="b"type="checkbox" name="car" value="Car"><br>
```

If because of my poor understanding of English i failed to understand correctly your question i apologize for making you lose time.